# Android Layout : On Top it takes too much of space

Tags: android, image, space

In my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/user_pswd_new_root" android:scrollbars="vertical" 
 android:soundEffectsEnabled="true">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/ScrollViewLogin" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal" android:visibility="visible">

 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:background="@drawable/logo_login" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:padding="0dp" android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

...............
  </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

With the above code, I set in a Dialog and things are shown proeprly, but there is lot of unwanted space above the image which unnecessarily increases the height of the dialog. See the results :
[image]

Any idea why the top space is occupied. And how do I get rid of it. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the title of the `Dialog`, which is empty because you didn't specify a title (but the view is still there). You have to remove it, for example like this:

```
class MyDialog extends Dialog {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // make sure to call requestWindowFeature before setContentView
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);
        // other initialization code
    }
    // ...
}
```

But that depends on whether you are using a simple `Dialog` or an `AlertDialog`. If this doesn't work for you, post your dialog-creation code (Java) and I'll update my answer to show how to remove the title in your case.

Comment: Felix, my class extends Dialog and this is how I show it :         ld = new LoginDialog(this);    
//ld.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
I added the above line in the constructor also, but I get error "Sorry .... unexpected error has caused" and the application shuts. If I comment that line then it works properly. Where am I going wrong ?  BTW, I can't findrequestWindowFeature().

Comment: I updated my answer. You should call it in `onCreate` instead of your constructor (the window doesn't exist at that point). And yeah, sorry about the method name. It's `requestWindowFeature` in `Dialog` and `requestFeature` in `Window`, I got them mixed up.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I added the method and it also worked. Was wondering why I can't see the onCreate() in methods to Overide, nor can add @Override tag on top of onCreate(). But things worked as expected. Any idea about this query.

Comment: I don't know, check the error / warning log in your IDE (I'm guessing Eclipse). Sounds like it might be just a problem with the IDE itself (since the method **is** getting called).